# Программа отдаёт разные ответы в разных компиляторах

Tags: c++, visual-c++, неопределённое-поведение

В онлайн компиляторе код (http://cpp.sh/4gnfb) при вводе:

```
4 1 2 3 4
```

выводит `YES`, а в Visual Studio - выводит `NO`.
Если вкратце, то код должен вывести `YES`, если среди `N` чисел присутствует 0. Я знаю, что это можно было бы написать проще и лаконичнее, мне важна сама проблема разного вывода. В чём может быть проблема? В онлайн компиляторе я потыкал разные версии c++, результат один и тот же.

Код ниже:

```
int main()
{
    int N, i = 0, a;
    cin >> N;
    bool NovyiGod2018;

    while (i < N)
    {
        cin >> a;

        if (a == 0)
        {
            NovyiGod2018 = 1;
        }
        else if (NovyiGod2018 != 1)
        {
            NovyiGod2018 = 0;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    if (NovyiGod2018 == 1)
    {
        cout << "YES";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO";
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам следует обращать внимание на предупреждения компилятора. Студия же прямо выдает `warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable 'NovyiGod2018' used`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема - в неинициализированной переменной `bool NovyiGod2018;`
Исправьте на

```
bool NovyiGod2018 = false;
```

в вашем онлайн-компиляторе, и получите `NO`.

И - для того и тип `bool`, чтоб иметь значения `true`/`false` - лучше использовать для него именно эти значения, а не 0/1...